# MarginLayoutParams.setMargins() is not working?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view

Here's the thing: I want to add some images programmatically. The images should have to have a `topMargin` of `5dip` except for the first image, in a `LinearLayout` with a `vertical orientation` manner. below the code segment:

```
LinearLayout body = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.body);

    for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {

        ImageView img = new ImageView(this);
        MarginLayoutParams lp = new MarginLayoutParams(-2, -2);

        img.setImageResource(R.drawable.image);
        if (i != 1) {

            lp.setMargins(0, 5, 0, 0);

        }
        img.setLayoutParams(lp);

        body.addView(img);
        body.requestLayout();
    }
```

By running the program I can see the the 4 images(here) vertically aligned one by one but there is no `topMargin`(as in the code,`5dip`). `body` is the `id` of the `LinearLayout`. here's the `XML` segment to:

```
<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/body"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#901b0e08"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="6dp"
            android:paddingRight="8dp" >
 </LinearLayout>
```

I cant get what went wrong here.

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try changing your `MarginLayoutParams` to this:

```
LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams( LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT );
```

The reason for doing this, is that `body` is a `LinearLayout` and thus you would want to use the `LinearLayout`-specific `LayoutParams`.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set `padding` but `margin` for ImageView. Sometimes it works fine. Your can directly set padding size to ImageView w/o declare `LayoutParams`.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to set LayoutParams' [gravity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Gravity.html) property, for example:

```
    lp.gravity = 0; //AXIS_X_SHIFT
```

That's what works fine for me.

Comment: I had a problem where setting margins for a FrameLayout worked on OS 4.x but seemed to have no effect running 2.3. Setting lp.gravity = Gravity.NO_GRAVITY fixed the problem on 2.3